# Joomla show contacts of subcategories

Tags: joomla2.5

Joomla 2.5

I created the following structure of contact categories :
Category 1 (does not contain any contact)
SubCategory 11 (contains contacts, Parent = Category 1)
SubCategory 12 (contains contacts, Parent = Category 1)

Coming from a menu type "List Contacts in a Category" I want to show a Contact page as this :
SubCategory 11 :
    Contact A
    Contact B
SubCategory 12 :
  Contact C
  Contact D

I copied the Category tmpl files in the html folder of my template and now the page shows :
SubCategory 11
SubCategory 12

Now I need to modify the script to show for each SubCategory but I can't see how I can access the contact items

Could anybody help me ?

Gustav